# Object matching using Feature Matching in Open CV

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, template-matching

I am new in OpenCV. I have used template matching to match a template image in a big image.
But using feature matching sometimes it is not matching. Size of my template is 40 X 40.

Please help me in this. One thing which I want to know that if template size is small will it effect to detect more features?

Comment: Do you use template matching or feature matching (with the feature of a template)? If you use feature matching, what kind of features do you use?

Comment: Image? Code? Problem?

Comment: Micka : I have used template matching and it is working perfectly fine. But for some special cases template matching is not working. Special cases are like, if template image contains a link, so when link can be underlined (hover effect), so it is not matching with the original one. So I switched on feature matching. But again I am facing same issue with feature matching.

Comment: a-Jays : It is not allowing me to post image. And I am using FAST and SURF for detecting and extracting features respectively.